# FlexSlider Fade animation broken in IE7&8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

My fade animation is broken in IE7 & 8.  rather than fade, the next slide contents are rendered, and both slides are present and mashed together for the specified animaionDuration.

Any fixes for this?

I posted to the FlexSlider 'support' feed, but it's not very well monitored so I'm turning to SO.

Here's my call:

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    slideshow: true,
    slideshowSpeed: 6000,
    animation: "fade",
    animationDuration: 500
});
```

FlexSlider Documentation here:

http://flex.madebymufffin.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem, to 'fix' the issue I used an if/else statement to remove the animationDuration from IE7/8 that flex slider uses.

It does mean it's not quite as pretty in IE8/7 but it fixes the issue and leaves all the latest browsers looking as you intended!

```
if ($().flexslider) {
    if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE 8.0;') > 0) {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            slideshowSpeed: 5000,
            animation: "fade",
            animationDuration: 0,
            controlNav: false,
            pauseOnHover: true,
            directionNav: true
        });
    } else{
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            slideshowSpeed: 5000,
            animation: "fade",
            controlNav: false,
            pauseOnHover: true,
            directionNav: true
        });
    }
};
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Works perfectly. Note that the `animationDuration` parameter is now `animationSpeed`.

Answer (score 0):

Unable to replicate.

However, I did get this in my error console. If this is causing something else to pitch an error for you, then it could be interrupting the propagation of some jQuery events.

```
http://web2carz.rawdesigns.net/common/js/awkward.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

If something in that script is vital, I can foresee issues.

Comment: That sheet is for a different slider in the full version of that page.  There's no relation to FlexSlider.  Thank you for checking!

Comment: Yea, but I ran your sample thrugh IE 7 and 8 and saw no issue.

Comment: It's an interesting issue, as it took time for the problem to start rendering in my atmosphere, as well as others on my team.  It's only IE7 & 8, and takes a few days from first viewing until it starts mashing slides together. Perhaps some bug in FlexSlider...  Maybe once we publish it will resolve itself.  Been developing locally for some time now...  Again, thanks for taking the time to check!

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that IE7 is not supporting the "fade" animation. I don't know why.
Based on all the answers above, I edited the script call as follows, and it worked.
For good browsers, I have the "fade" effect and for IE7, I have the "slide" effect.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
    if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE 7.0;') > 0) {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animation: "slide"
        });
    } else {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider();
    }
});
</script>
```